# How do I correctly sort merged arrays in a template file?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type in Drupal 8 with some fields referencing to taxonomy terms. I like to display these terms all together in one sorted array, so I merge the fields and sort them. But the result is always incompletely sorted, some terms are moved, but the others stay in the order they are saved. I tried different ways for sorting: sort function

```
{% for t in node.field_x|merge(node.field_y)|merge...|sort((a, b) => a.entity.name.value < b.entity.name.value ? -1 : (a.entity.name.value > b.entity.name.value ? 1 : 0)) %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

I tried it with strcmp

```
|sort((a, b) => strcmp(a.entity.name.value, b.entity.name.value))
```

and I tried it with a Twig extension function in a new module. It's always the same wrong result. So obviously I am wrong at some important point.

Can you help me?

Comment: A suggestion, with complex logic you can use process your logic in hook_preprocess. It's easy to process and easy to maintain. Remember twig is template engine.

Comment: Thanks @Jonh, I solved it with a theme_preprocess_node function.